# How can I speed up my MVC asp.net website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, performance, optimization

Hi Everyone I am working on my first MVC 3 website built in C# in asp.net I am having some trouble with with the speed of the website as it takes over 45 seconds to expand or contract the tables that show the database.

I have included my code for the reportTemplate which has my jquery on it

I have been trying to figure out how to use cache but I am worried that the data will not be up to date when the managers need up to date data

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "ReportTemplate";
}

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    toggle = function (className) {
        $('.' + className).toggle('fast');
    }


});

</script>

<h2>ReportTemplate</h2>

<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")    
</p>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>
        INVESTMENT AREA
    </th>
    <th>
        MAJOR PROGRAM
    </th>
    <th>
        MANAGER
    </th>
    <th>
        PROJECT
    </th> 
    <th>
        SPA
    </th>
    <th>
        PA
    </th>                                 
</tr>

@{
string investment_area = "";
string major_program = "";
string manager = "";
string project = "";
string spa = ""; 
string pa = "";
string iaClass = "";
string mpClass = "";
string manClass = "";
string pjClass = "";
string spaClass = "";
string paClass = "";
}
    @foreach (var item in Model)
{
iaClass = item.investment_area.Substring(0, 2);
mpClass = item.major_program;
manClass = item.manager;
pjClass = item.project;
spaClass = item.spa;
paClass = item.pa;

    if (investment_area != item.investment_area)
{

<tr>        
  <td class = "ndeTable ui-widget-header pointer border" onclick="toggle('@iaClass')" colspan="6">
        @item.investment_area
    </td>
</tr>

}
investment_area = item.investment_area;

if (major_program != item.major_program)
{

<tr class="@iaClass">
<td style = "width :200px"></td>
    <td class = "ndeTable pointer border" onclick="toggle('@mpClass')" colspan="5">

    @item.major_program

    </td>
</tr>    
}
major_program = item.major_program;

if (manager != item.manager)
{                
<tr class = "@iaClass @mpClass">
<td></td>
<td style = "width : 100px"></td>
    <td class = "ndeTable pointer border" onclick="toggle('@manClass')" colspan="4">    
    @item.manager
    </td>                
</tr>
}
manager = item.manager;

if (project != item.project)
{
<tr class = "@iaClass @mpClass @manClass">

<td></td>
<td></td>
<td style = "width : 200px"></td>

   <td class = "ndeTable pointer border" onclick = "toggle('@pjClass')" colspan="3">
   @item.project
   </td>
</tr>
}
project = item.project;

if (spa != item.spa)
{
<tr class = "@iaClass @mpClass @manClass @pjClass">

<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td style = "width : 325px"></td>

    <td class = "ndeTable pointer border" onclick = "toggle('@spaClass')" colspan = "2">
    @item.spa
    </td>
</tr>
}
spa = item.spa;


<tr class = "@iaClass @mpClass @manClass @pjClass @spaClass">
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td style = "width: 200px"></td>
    <td class = "ndeTable pointer border" onclick = "toggle('@paClass')" colspan = "1">
    @item.pa
    </td>           
</tr>

pa = item.pa;
}
</table>
```

I am going to continue trying to optimize the code in the meantime but if anyone has any tips or tricks I can use I would be very thankful as this has been troubling me for the past couple days and 45 secs for a small database is ridiculous. Thank you for your time.
Cheers,
James

Comment: What do you mean "expand/contract"? The MVC code is only going to affect the page load speed, not any JQuery UI activity.

Comment: When you click on say an investment area cell the children of that investment area are supposed to expand or contract to show or hide the major programs managers spa etc... I am sorry if I was vague as this is my first question I am still working out the right question to ask and thank you for your quick response!

Comment: Does anyone think it could be the toggle function the jQuery is calling because that is the part of the site that really slows down everything. Is there another way to make the table expand or contract the investment area children without going extremely slow like it is now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fire up sql profiler/sql trace and check out how many queries you are doing during single http request that creates the page. Queries are often the one to blame for performance issues. It's nearly impossible that solely rendering the view takes so much time.

Comment: I have fired up SQL profiler and started a new trace but what exactly am I looking for? Should I be looking for long trace durations or lots of reads and writes? I want to thank you for your quick response as well!

Comment: In this case look for a lots of reads. What is the number of queries issued to grab all data for the page? Specifically, if you are using an ORM, you may have select n+1 issue.

Answer (score 0):

It might happen that you have too many records that you are trying to display in the table. You should use paging. Take a look at [datatables.net](http://datatables.net) It is a nice jquery plugin that will help you with paging. Make sure that you are using [server side processing](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/server_side/server_side.html). Of course, you will have to change a lot in your code (both server side and client side).

Comment: I can't really use paging as this website needs to be a quick view of current projects and investment areas. That is why I am using the toggle so that all the information is on one page for easy access for the technology impaired. Thank you though for your quick response!

Comment: How many rows do you display on the page? Also, can you post a database query that you are executing on the server side?

Comment: it looks like it has nothing to do with the sql queries I definitely  think it is the toggle function I just improved the speed by 20 seconds by changing toggle to slideToggle

Answer (score 0):

Which browser are you working with? Older browsers don't have the Javascript performance of the newer ones and with the number of panels you could be simultaneously exposing or hiding that is undoubtedly the cause of your issue.

I agree with the answer that deals with paging, that would be a good option reduce the amount of data you are presenting in one go or you must reduce the number of elements you are revealing simultaneously. Javascript execution isn't instant and on the old browsers it's really slow.